# Class's not supported for deserialization of an array

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net

I have this error(image):
[image: I have this error(image)]

My code:

```
function CheckLoginData() {

var user = [];
user.Email = $("#tbEmail").val();
user.Password = $("#tbPassword").val();


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf=8",
    url: "WS.asmx/CheckAccount",
    data: "{user:" + JSON.stringify(user) + "}",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d);
    },
    error: function (request, status, error) {
        alert("Erro : " + request.responseText);
    }
});
```

}

**Why this error is happening? I've tried to search deeply but without success**

Comment: Please, use text to provide an exception message [instead of images](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/).

Comment: try `user={}` and then `data: '{"user" : " + JSON.stringify(user) + "}'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You assign an empty array to `user`

```
var user = [];
```

But then you treat it as an object by assigning fields to it, it confuses the serialiser.

You will need to declare `user` to be an object

```
var user = { Email: $("#tbEmail").val(), Password: $("#tbPassword").val() };
```